# Autoplay next embedded soundcloud track?

Tags: php, wordpress, embed, soundcloud

I'm currently using http://ifttt.com to grab my public favourites from SoundCloud and post them to my Wordpress site (http://diversesounds.co.uk).

IFTTT creates a post on my site with the following contents;

```
<div class="trackUrl" id="(IFTTT then grabs the Track URL and places it here)">
```

I then have the following block of JS;

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>

<?php

if(have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php

// Exploding the content to get track url from Div ID
$theContent = get_the_content();
$explode = explode('"', $theContent);
$trackUrl = $explode[3];

?>

SC.oEmbed(
    "<?php echo $trackUrl; ?>",
    {
        color: "494e72",
        show_comments: false
    },
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $trackUrl; ?>")
);

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The above code works perfectly but what I would like it to do is autoplay the next track after finishing the first manually played track.

Comment: @Joel I haven't tried any methods as of yet as I'm not 100% sure where to start at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a listener for the onMediaEnd event and try to play the next track with that:

```
soundcloud.addEventListener('onMediaEnd', function(player, data) {

    // find the next player here and use the API method api_play()

});
```

Docs: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget#widget-events

You'll probably need to swap out the embed method though. Their JS wrapper is on GitHub

https://github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API

Comment: The link you posted is for Flash Widget, sorry for confusion, please edit.

Comment: Hello Stephen, I'll be honest that went completely over my head. I know next to nothing about JS. Please see the update post for a better explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [HTML5 Widget API documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget).

You could attach event handlers to `FINISH` events. However, my recommendation would be to use a different approach and go with [Audio5JS](http://zohararad.github.io/audio5js/), [SoundCloud's own JS SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks) or [kilokeith/soundcloud-soundmanager-player](https://github.com/kilokeith/soundcloud-soundmanager-player). You could then build UI yourself and play all the music with player.

The difference is that each widget is quite a complex single-page JS application and is not really intended for the purpose you are trying to use it for.

**UPD**. example flow (just out of my head):

```
collect references to all widget iframes by DOM class
store them in array `widgets`
initialise API wrapper with first element of that array `SC.Widget(widgets[0])`
attach event handler `finishHandler` to `FINISH` event
`finishHandler` needs to 
  initialise API wrapper `SC.Widget(widgets[1])` and start playback with this new widget 
  attach the same `finishHandler` to `FINISH` event of the newly initialised widget
  shift first widget from the array `widgets.shift()`
```

This is probably too simple and naive. But maybe it'll still help you.

Comment: I'm currently using [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) to add my public favourites as blog posts on the website which is using Wordpress. If I change the way I use the player this will no longer work.

Is there another way around this?

Comment: well then you'd need to rely on the HTML5 Widget API. Updated the answer with flow to follow.

Comment: I am not really familiar with IFTTT, but if you could customise the HTML that is posted to Wordpress, then you could still use custom JavaScript player and build your own UI for it.

Comment: In brief, IFTTT lets you use certain data called 'Ingredients'. This is the list of ingredients that can be used; http://cl.ly/image/041m1H1u3s1w. As you can see I'm using the embed code option at the moment. What data from each track would I need to create my own player? Track ID?

Comment: You could probably do it with track URL. Then, with JS you'd hit `resolve` [endpoint](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) that would redirect you to track representation. At that point you'd have all the information to both build UI (artwork url, user/sound url etc.) and initialise a sound

Comment: Please see updated post for a better explanation, thank-you for your help so far.

Comment: Hey Joe, unfortunately your task requires knowledge of JavaScript.